# How to use two number to form a Jones polynomial

Tags: polynomials, knot-theory

According to the [Wikipedia article on Knots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_%28mathematics%29),

[image]

The number of crossing (rule $1$) and a line crossing the triangle (rule $2$) form a number such as $3,1$. With these two numbers, how do you form a Jones polynomial?

**update**
Where does $t^{3/2}$ come from, where is a variable for 3 to substitute in (6.7)(6.8)(6.9)?

How do notation come out from skein relation?

Where do $V_{O_2}(t)$ come from  and equal to what number?

How does $V_{\sigma^3}$ become a combination of $V_\sigma$ and $V_{\sigma^2}$

Comment: The linked article mentions nothing about this. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: i add a picture which i do not understand V(3,2) form a polynomial

Comment: In your picture, Equations (6.7)-(6.9) give a recipe to recursively determine the Jones polynomial by Skein relations (see here for the picture of $K_\pm$ and $K_0$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_polynomial#Properties). $V_{T(3,2)}$ denotes the Jones polynomial of the trefoil knot $T(2,3)$ (the notation comes from the fact that the trefoil is the (2,3)-torus knot). I can't make sense of what you are trying to say about "rule 1," "rule 2," and what the numbers you mention are supposed to be. The Wikipedia article you link still has no relation to the question other than being about knots.

Comment: could you demonstrate the final two steps in diagram, when i see the properties, i just know crossing is separated in two kind of crossing, one is on top of another. i do not understand how do notation come out from skein relation? and how do t^(3/2) come from, where is a variable for 3 to substitute in (6.7)(6.8)(6.9)

Comment: Draw the knot, with the braid $\sigma^3$. Now switch the top crossing either from an overcrossing to an undercrossing or from an undercrossing to an overcrossing. Then by Reidemeister's 2nd move, 2 crossings will be out, so we are left with $\sigma$. Then change the top crossing to a "no-crossing", then two crossings are left, so we have $\sigma^2$. Now put into the skein relation, and solve.